# Draw Text on CameraPreview (Android)

Tags: android, text, opengl-es, camera

Basically I'm able to draw a simple text over the CameraPreview using a View:

```
    class DrawOnTop extends View {



    public DrawOnTop(Context context) {

            super(context);

            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }



    @Override

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            Paint paint = new Paint();

            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            paint.setFakeBoldText(true);


            canvas.drawText("Test Text", 
                    30,
                    30, paint);

            super.onDraw(canvas);

    }
```

}

But I'd like to have something like a "toast", at the bottom of the camera preview, rather than a simple text like that. I can give you an example of what I mean, just take a look at this image:

http://www.lemacinaie.it/amiata/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/realta_aumentata.jpg

I'd like to achieve the same thing, I have tried opengles without success... can anyone help? thank you.

EDIT: Im able to bind the camerapreview in a GLSurfaceView, i just need to know how to draw a box with text inside it, just like a toast, in OpenGLES. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The camera preview goes either to a SurfaceView or is fed in encoded form to a custom callback that you specify. SurfaceViews are not designed for compositing with other widgets, so your only option is to decode the preview yourself and composite it off-screen before drawing it to your own on-screen widget (which can be a SurfaceView).

See this [3D-Compass](https://github.com/ldo/3D-Compass) app for an example of how to do off-screen compositing, in this case of OpenGL graphics combined with the camera preview. You should be able to adapt the source code to your needs.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried to run your code on my phone and it throws an exception: 02-08 12:17:40.207: E/AndroidRuntime(3738): nz.gen.geek_central.Compass3D.EGLUseful$EGLException: EGL creating Pbuffer surface failed with error 12288
anyway I have done something like that with OpenGLES. I know how to bind the camera preview, I just need to draw the box with the text inside like in that image, and in the "OnDraw" method I don't know how to do it, just like a toast, at the bottom of the preview. Could you give an example with OpenGLES which draws what I am asking?. Thank you for your help!